# How to rename a file which already stored in the server using laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I have a form which has an upload file inside it. If I want to edit the data and edit the file(upload new file), it's works. But if I want to edit the data without uploading a new file (example the mail's name, because the file's name depends on the mail's name), it works just change the file name in the database without rename a file which stored in the server, so when I click view file, I have got an error the file is not found. Do you know how to replace a file name?

```
$destination = 'files';

    if($request->hasFile('ubah_upload_file')) {
        $file = $request->file('ubah_upload_file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name =  str_replace('/','_',$request['ubah_nomor_surat']) . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move($destination, $file_name );
    } else {
        $file_name =  str_replace('/','_',$request['ubah_nomor_surat']) . '.' . "pdf";
    }
```

Comment: Use `rename($oldname , $newname);` to rename a file.

Comment: Could you show me how to use it? because it's my first time using uploading file like this. Or maybe you know the references that looks similar with my case?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rename()` [function](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.rename.php) to rename a file

Ps: update the name in the db too if you rename it permanently